# can't find targeting class in select java application

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to run an open source Java project in Eclipse (EE), which requires me to run each module as a Java application, however after clicking that, I couldn't find the targeting class in the pop up window. Any clue how to resolve this?

I'm using Macos now, and I have ran it without problem on linux before.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If that project has main method, as soon as you click on run as "Java Application" it should show you the option to select main class, find out manual where is main class and give input,...it should work.